# How can I formalise a proof of this?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

A question from a textbook:

> Take the interval $(a,b)$, split into thirds likewise:
>
> $$(a,b)=\Big(a,\tfrac{1}{3} (2a+b)\Big)\bigcup \Big[\tfrac13(2a+b),\tfrac13 (2b+a)\Big]\bigcup \Big(\tfrac{1}{3} (2b+a),b\Big)$$
>
> Retain the middle interval, and perform the same on the two outer
>   intervals, i.e. split them into thirds and retain the middle closed
>   interval.
>
> $$\text{etc.}$$
>
> Is the disjoint union of the retained intervals $(a,b)?$

I've drawn a picture to illustrate the process, in case it isn't clear:

[image]

In black are the remaining open intervals after each step, and in red is the union of the closed intervals after each step. Since the retained intervals are closed, we do not lose endpoints, so it seems likely that the resulting union is  $(a,b)$.

How could I prove it formally? My idea was to consider an arbitrary element of $(a,b)$ and show that it belongs to the union after a finite number of steps, but I am having trouble making it concrete.

Comment: This is the [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set); it is non-empty and thus it's complement is no equal to $(a,b)$

Comment: @AlexR Are you sure though? I thought it was a trick question: the Cantor set is the same process but with all open intervals replaced with closed intervals, and vise versa. Doesn't this make a difference?

Comment: It's the *complement* of the Cantor set.

Comment: @RyanReich I apologise if I am being daft - but I don't think the left over set (what we get from the intervals in black) is the Cantor set. The Cantor set is non empty because we retain the endpoints of each interval, whereas here the intervals in black are all open - so the end result could well be empty (and hence the set of interest, in red, could be the whole of $(a,b)$) - no?

Comment: Oh, I misread the question.

Comment: @user111064 I seem to have gotten confused about the notation. With that in mind, pick a fixed $x$ outside of a closed interval (say the distance is $\epsilon$), then you'll eventually have the maximum gap between the closed intervals be $<\epsilon$ and since they are closed, $x$ is in the union.

Comment: Though this isn't the complement of the Cantor set, it does seem to be understandable through the ternary representation of numbers deleted from the Cantor set. In constructing the Cantor set, we delete any number that contains a 1 in its ternary representation. But here, all we're doing is deleting anything with a 1 and anything that terminates in a string of 0's at the end, e.g. 0.20000... Thus, I contend that 3/4 = 0.202020... in ternary is a counterexample for a = 0 and b = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is to be answered with no; WLOG assuming $(a,b) = (0,1)$.
@HughDenoncourt pointed out, that $\frac34 = 0.\overline{20}_3$ will never become part of any $A_i$ by construction of $A_i$ and thus $\frac34 \notin A$.
($A_i$ is the union of the closed sets up to the $i$-th iteration, $A = \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N} A_i$ is the set in question)

---

More generally a number $x$ is in $A$ iff there is a ternary representation of $x$ which contains a $1$, so that it is in the middle of a third or at the border to the middle third.

Comment: The countable intersection of open sets is usually not an open set.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I had my mind twisted. I'll fix this.  
To recite the correct statements: The countable union of open sets is open and the countable intersection of closed sets is closed.

Comment: I avoided writing it up as an answer because it's somewhat hard to formalize the answer :) With effort it can be made clean.

Comment: Oh! This question was better than I thought - thank you for the answer. Would I be correct in saying that the left-over set, though not the Cantor set, is uncountable?

Comment: Yes. We can associate any ternary representation with 2's and 0's to a sequence of 1's and 0's, or equivalently, a subset of the natural numbers. (The number $n$ is in the associated subset if there is a 2 in the $n$-th place.) However, unlike the Cantor set, we'll be omitting anything that ends in an infinite string of 0's or 2's. The left-over set subtracts a countable set from the Cantor set. Hence, it is uncountable.